# Executed malicious exe file. Help please

Tags: malware

windows 8.1
Im not very computer savvy i was wondering if someone could help me out with this.
So I downloaded an exe file then ran it as administrator. It turns out it was a virus. Yeah I'm a genius.

File is called Extractor__8680_i1435468059_il22

Shortly afterwards BITSADMIN tool came up in command prompt all on its own and either uploaded or downloaded something or did something which i have never seen before before quickly closing itself. It mentioned a windows32 file.
Afterwards I activated malwarebytes and then shortly after that malwarebytes said it stopped a suspicious action on my computer, but i still feel my system is compromised.

I have tried running a few antivirus programs, making sure to check for rootkits even but it doesn't seem to help.

After a while my computer restart all on its own.

I'm at a loss at what to do but im guessing a factory reset is in order?

Comment: Disconnect the machine from the network RIGHT NOW. Then, read [how do I deal with a compromised server](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server).

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to know from this description if your computer is compromised -- but it sounds like you're prepared to do a factory reset. For your peace of mind, and for the integrity of your system, that's what I'd recommend.

If you have access to a backup from which you can restore only records timestamped before you downloaded the malicious executable, that's the way to go. If not, I recommend backing up your data to an external drive. Don't reconnect that drive until you have reset the system, installed a good antivirus program, and performed all updates to the operating system and the antivirus program. Then connect the external drive, scan the files using that antivirus program, and (if they pass the scan) copy them back to your hard drive.

Then I recommend reformmating the external drive.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me i appreciate it.

Comment: Depending upon what data you deal with, you may want to consider a 'nuke from orbit' approach as it is possible for the BIOS to become infected and thus a reformat would clean the machine.  If this is a work computer, you'd best have IT make that call.